# Assign 1 arbitrary row as primary per group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with three columns,

```
foo_id | bar_id | is_primary
```

Now after importing a huge amount of records the id pairs are all in but the `is_primary` is 0 everywhere, I need to assign 1 arbitrary row per `foo_id` as `is_primary` = 1?

foo_id | bar_id are the primary unique keys, however both foo_id and bar_id can appear multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the `(foo_id, bar_id)` pairs are unique and `is_primary` is restricted to have either 0 or 1 (i.e. no other values or NULLs), you could determine, for example, the minimum `bar_id` value for every `foo_id` value and set `is_primary` to 1 for the corresponding rows:

```
UPDATE atable t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      foo_id,
      MIN(bar_id) AS bar_id
    FROM atable
    GROUP BY foo_id
    HAVING MAX(is_primary) = 0
  ) s ON t.foo_id = s.foo_id AND t.bar_id = s.bar_id
SET t.is_primary = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(foo_id,bar_id)` is unique, you could use a `not exists` clause to filter the highest value of `bar_id` per `foo_id`:

```
update  YourTable yt1
set     is_primary = 1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.foo_id = yt1.foo_id
                and yt2.bar_id > yt1.bar_id
        )
```